# Save entire jupyter notebook as HTML with the interactive plotly graphe

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, plotly, r-plotly

I tried to save my jupyter notebook as HTML but the plotly graph becomes static

I can save the graph separately with `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(fig, "index.html")` but this only saves the graphe and I need the full page with it.

Is there a way to save the entire page as well as the interactive graphes?

I am using R